# Using .sort(), sorted(), and .reverse() methods on lists

Tags: python, list, methods

I'm following a tutorial which asks me
to reverse the list in alphabetical order and then print it. I wrote this code:

```
visit_list = ["Alaska", "Norway", "Canada", "Germany", "Russia"]
print(visit_list)
print(sorted(visit_list))
print(visit_list)
```

The problem arises when I try to do it how I thought would work (which it kinda did) by doing the following.

```
visit_list.sort()
print(visit_list.reverse())
```

Now this did reverse the list, but the output code came out as simply "None". Why?

Comment: In what way did this "work" if you did not want the output to be `None`?

Comment: It worked because it reversed the list

Answer (score 0):

```
visit_list.reverse()
```

Is a method which reverses the list but doesn't return anything it just do the reversing on the calling list which is `visit_list`.

So when this line executes:

```
print(visit_list.reverse())
```

It prints `None` because it is the returning value from executing that method which is `None` as it doesn't return anything to the line in which it was called.

But it actually does its job to reverse the list but simply doesn't return any value.

You can read more about the `return` statement which is used inside of a function to return a value to the caller (https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/).

So a quick fix to your code is simply to print the list after it was reversed using the reverse method:

```
visit_list.reverse()
print(visit_list)
```

Comment: Everything you said works. Although, I do need to add onto this by also alphabetically sorting it at the same time. I'm trying all that I know currently but I would very much appreciate your help on this also.

Comment: `visit_list.sort(reverse = True)`

Comment: this will sort the list in descending order alphabetically.